# SSIS: Working with 3 constrains where 2 should be OR and one should be AND

Tags: ssis-2016

So I have an SSIS flow in which I am working with three constraint within a task, but 2 of them must be an OR and one must be an AND. In pseudo-code would be something like:

```
if ( (constraint-a OR constraint-b) AND constraint-c)
```

Problem is, we can only set OR/AND to all precedents:

[image: Precedence Constraint Editor: Multiple constraints]

Are there any solutions in which we could group some of these constraints?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. It seems as though it's a clever solution that works as intended. if I'm following correctly.

Comment: @Zane It might be clever but it feels a little dirty. I wonder if I can do it without the Empty container in the middle.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this diagram is an over-simplification. I would have to add about 20 of those empty containers in production!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my original solution for this problem, which apparently is not as bad as I thought. The only problem with it is that the designer canvas can get quite crowded.

I managed to achieve the desired solution with a little *kludge*, which gives me exactly what I want. However I can't help but feel a little dirty doing it, so I wonder if there is a better way. Here is a diagram of what I have done:

[image: Diagram of flow]

**NOTE:** It is important to emphasise that I need `Main Script B` to start as soon as `Main Script A` completes.

**Script Task B1** is the one requiring the complex constraint. As you can see in the centre of the diagram, I grouped failure of `Main Script A` and completion of `Script Task A2` in an empty container.

This allows for script tasks `A1` and `A2` to be bypassed if `Main Script A` fails, and `Script Task B1` to be executed after previous script tasks have been completed. But `Script Task B1` must wait for Main Script B to finish as well.

Here are the results using this cheap kludge:

**When Main Script A succeeds:**
[image: Main Script A Success]

**When Main Script A fails:**
[image: Main Script A Failure]

I wonder if there are alternatives to this solution, though.